# Lua class constructor implementation

Tags: class, lua, constructor

So, in this concept of OOP in Lua where classes are metatables and all, I am struggling to understand the differences in some things:

For example, in the code below:

```
Account = {}

function Account:new(balance)
  local t = setmetatable({}, { __index = Account })

  -- Your constructor stuff
  t.balance = (balance or 0)
  return t
end
```

Why to use the `__index` MT and more specifically, to set it to `Account`. And what is the `Account` ? Does it reffer to the initial table defined in the first line? So the `__index` is set to an empty table?

And why not doing it like this then

```
Account = {}

function Account:new(balance)
  local t = {} -- No metatable here. Just an empty default table

  -- Your constructor stuff
  t.balance = (balance or 0)
  return t
end
```

What are the differences of the two classes ? And why, in the case where there is a metatable we have to set `{ __index = <classname> }` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: An object created with `obj = setmetatable({}, { __index = Account })` is able to access methods defined in `Account`, for example, `obj:withdraw(100)` is invoking `Account.withdraw(obj, 100)` under the hood.  Of course, `obj.balance` is contained only in `obj`, this field is absent in `Account`

Answer (score 1):

```
local t = setmetatable({}, { __index = Account }
```

creates a table with a metatable where `__index` is `Account`.

That means if a field is not present in `t` it will be looked up in `Account`.

That's what makes `t` an instance of `Account`.

If you just use your second snipped you will simply return a table that is not related to `Account` in any way.

> And what is the Account

Account is the global table you created in your first line. You could also write

```
function Account:new(balance)
  local t = setmetatable({}, { __index = self })
```

In most examples you'll find something like

```
Account = {}
function Account:new()
  local o = setmetatable({}, self)
  self.__index = self
  return o
end
```

Comment: "if a field is not present in `t` it will be looked up in Account..." : Why would I want to modify a field that is not present in an instance of the class? If I am instantiating an object then I know exactly which fields are present. So if I understand correctly, this is only for the case that i want to somehow...extend the instance by adding more fields to it after i have created it?

Comment: well how is your object an instance of Account if you don't relate it somehow? how does object know anything about Account's methods? by making the instance's __index Account you ensure that you have access to everything in Account. say you have a method Account:print(), instance:print() would throw an error for calling a nil value. with __index = Account Lua will call Account's print with self referring to your instance.

Comment: What if my object is similar to python's style `@dataclass` where it is ment to only hold values? And by this I mean that you create the object and then you read/write its fields. You do not have an other method. Then not setting an ``__index`` would work. Right? In the case that there are more 1 methods associated to the object, based on your input, then I need a reference to the class e.g., `Account` in the example. Right?